Borel-Moore homology for resolution of singularities
Let $X$ be a singular projective variety. Denote by $Z$ the singular locus of $X$. Consider the resolution of singularities $$\pi: \widetilde{X} \to X$$
Denote by $E$ the exceptional divisor. We know that there is a long exact sequence in cohomology given by:
$$... \to H^{i-1}(E) \to H^i(X) \to H^i(\widetilde{X}) \oplus H^i(Z) \to H^i(E) \to ...$$
Is there a similar exact sequence using Borel-Moore homology, instead of cohomology? If necessary, assume that $Z$ is a union of finitely many points.

Everything here is compact, so Borel-Moore homology is just homology.

Sure, is there a similar exact sequence using homology?

Yes: just reverse the direction of the arrows.

Thanks, can you suggest a reference.

@user45397 Could you give a reference (or a proof sketch) for the above cohomology long exact sequence?

Borel-Moore homology is actually the easiest variant of (co)homology to prove this in. More generally let $\pi \colon Y \to X$ be a proper morphism which induces an isomorphism away from a closed subscheme $Z \subset X$. Write $E := \pi^{-1}(Z)$.  Then we have the distinguished triangles
$$ C^{BM}_*(Z) \to C^{BM}_*(X) \to C^{BM}_*(X-Z) \to $$
$$ C^{BM}_*(E) \to C^{BM}_*(Y) \to C^{BM}_*(Y-E) \to $$
There is a map of distinguished triangles, from bottom to top, given by proper pushforward, which induces a quasi-isomorphism on the cones/cofibers. So the square
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
C^{BM}_*(E) @>>> C^{BM}_*(Y) \\
@V{\pi_*}VV @V{\pi_*}VV \\
C^{BM}_*(Z) @>>> C^{BM}_*(X)
\end{CD}$$
is homotopy coCartesian as it induces quasi-isomorphisms on the cones of the horizontal maps. Equivalently there is a distinguished triangle
$$ C^{BM}_*(E) \to C^{BM}_*(Y) \oplus C^{BM}_*(Z) \to C^{BM}_*(X) \to $$
which gives rise to the long exact sequence you asked for.
When $X$ is proper, you can then rewrite this using homology or cohomology.
